# Why am I seeing ridges on a cloth simulation?

Tags: collision

I'm new to blender and have been playing round with a simple cloth and collision animation made from a simple UV sphere and plane.

I added a subdivision to the sphere to smooth it out and subdivisions to the plane to allow to wrap.

[image]
[image]

Then I created the collision process and ran the animation.

[image]

However, even though my sphere is as smooth as it can be - it appears to have ridges when the cloth is placed over it.

[image]

It's as if the subdivision on the sphere is less than it appears.

I've [attached](https://we.tl/t-E8SU1TeEl3) a file for reference in case it's not showing clearly on screen

Comment: It seems pretty obvious to me that you did not smooth out the sphere when you subdivided it. I recommend starting again and just creating a new sphere, but setting the correct number of rings and loops to start with. Either that, or just select all and “Transform -> To sphere.”

Comment: As *TheLabCat* wrote you probably baked the sim, then added subdivisions to the sphere to make it smoother. But you did not delete the bake. Now Blender still uses the old blocky shape. To fix this just delete the bake (*Settings > Cache*) and bake it again. Then it will look smooth.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Blunder and TheLabCat already mentioned - just hit "delete all bakes" and run the simulation again (e.g. just by tapping spacebar in 3D View or hit "bake" after deleting the bake)

[image]

result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the smoothing, you can adjust some of the parameters of the simulation to change, for instance, how stiff the cloth is.  There are a set of presets you can select from using the drop down menu in the *Cloth* simulation panel header:

[image: Cloth simulation drop down]

I suggest playing with those, and then adjusting the parameters of the simulation to taste.

To greatly reduce folding, first set the defaults to *Silk*, then  go to the *Physical Properties* tab, reduce the *Air Viscosity*, and change the *Bending Model* to linear:

[image: Physical Properties Tab with low air viscosity and linear bending model]

If you do that and redo the bake you get this at frame 34:

[image: mostly smooth drape]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131339/discussion-on-answer-by-marty-fouts-why-am-i-seeing-ridges-on-a-cloth-simulation).